# An invalid or illegal selector was specified - Protractor code issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, protractor

I have written the xpath in the below format for selecting the country from the dropdown, but getting the error as mentioned in the title.

```
sendKeys(undefined, 
  element(by.xpath("
      .//*[@id='/declaration/parties[partyRoleType="EX"]/physicalAddress/countryCode]'/span/input")), "GB", undefined, true, 5);
```

When tried to search the xpath

```
".//*[@id='/declaration/parties[partyRoleType="EX"]/physicalAddress/countryCode]'/span/input"
```

in web console, the element is found, but the above xpath is showing as error in VSC. Any help on the same is highly appreciated and if you could let me know how to handle the dropdowns in protractor, I would be more than thankfull.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show how you are using that sendKeys command in your code?

Comment: Try `".//*[@id='/declaration/parties[partyRoleType=\"EX\"]/physicalAddress/countryCode]'/span/input"` , you need to use \  to escape the nested  `"`

Comment: Yong, you are a champ, this fixed my issue, i was literally struggling for a week. Thanks a ton.